# Using PromptOptions's PromptStyler class with Microsoft.Bot.Builder #4.0

Tags: c#, botframework, prompt

I'm currently using Microsoft's Bot Framework and find myself in need of using choice-based prompts.

I'm using the PromptOptions class to build the options for my prompt. However, the property PromptStyler, which was available in Bot.Builder #3.0 to style the prompt, is gone in version #4.0, which I'm using (and can't change).

Is there any way to style the prompt in the same way the PromptStyler did for PromptOptions class back in Bot.Builder #3.0?

Thank you!

Appended:

PromptOptions class as per Bot.Builder #3.0:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptoptions-1?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0

PromptOptions class as per Bot.Builder #4.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptoptions?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) regarding prompt dialogs in V4.

V4 has an enum called `ListStyle` that's the equivalent of V3's `PromptStyle`. You use it by setting a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choiceprompt.style?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_ChoicePrompt_Style) of the `ChoicePrompt` object when you create it rather than a property of `PromptOptions` when you call the prompt.

```
Dialogs = new DialogSet(_dialogStateAccessor);
var cp = new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE);
cp.Style = Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.ListStyle.None;
Dialogs.Add(cp);
```

That prompt can be called like this:

```
await dc.PromptAsync(CHOICE, promptOptions);
```