# PromptStyler equivalent for BotFramework v4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm porting a project from Microsoft BotFramework SDK v3 to v4 and I'm sending prompts like so:

```
var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
var prompt = new PromptStyler(PromptStyle.Auto);
prompt.Apply(ref message, "some text", somePromptOptions);
using (var connector = CreateConnector())
{
    /* some stuff prior to sending the activity */
    await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
}
```

After installing the packages for v4 SDK, `PromptStyler` is no longer available. I don't use Dialogs, I always create messages from scratch and send them with the connector. How can I achieve the same result for prompts using BotFramework SDK v4?

Comment: Could you please tell me which kind of Prompt you want to use？ Choice or else?  Since the new version of Bot SDK doesn't contains the connector, we use turn instead and if you want to send something, you could only try to use different dialog.

Comment: @BrandoZhang it's a choice prompt, for yes/no options. I'm still able to use `ConnectorClient` tho.

Answer (score 0):

V4 has an enum called ListStyle that's the equivalent of V3's PromptStyle.
more information check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311585/using-promptoptionss-promptstyler-class-with-microsoft-bot-builder-4-0)

Comment: I've seen this, but it uses dialogs, I'm not using dialogs.